# Solving a SQL question with a subquery as opposed to a JOIN

Tags: sql

I have solved the below question using an inner join, however, it only returns 1 row and doesn't account for a scenario where there is more than 1 deployment location with tied highest ride counts. I believe this needs to be solved using a subquery.

Q: Which deployment location had the most number of rides over the past week?

**rides table:**

```
ride_id: int[primary key]

bike_id: int

ride_datetime:string

duration: int
```

**deployment table:**

```
bike_id [Primary Key]

deploy_location: string
```

**Answer:**

```
SELECT deploy_location

 FROM deployed_bikes

 WHERE bike_id >= ALL  (SELECT COUNT(ride_id)

                      FROM rides

                      WHERE to_date(ride_date, 'YYYY-MON-DD') BETWEEN (current_date - 7) AND 
 (current_date - 1))
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer just doesn't look correct at all.  You are comparing something called `bike_id` to a count.

I don't really know what "best" means.  But I would expect this to be closer to an answer to the question:

```
SELECT d.deploy_location, COUNT(*)
FROM deployed_bikes db JOIN
     rides r
     ON r.bike_id = dl.bike_id
WHERE to_date(ride_date, 'YYYY-MON-DD') BETWEEN (current_date - 7) AND (current_date - 1))
GROUP BY d.deploy_location
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;  -- some databases might use LIMIT or something else
```

If you want multiple rows in the event of a tie, I would suggest window functions:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (SELECT d.deploy_location, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM deployed_bikes db JOIN
           rides r
           ON r.bike_id = dl.bike_id
      WHERE to_date(ride_date, 'YYYY-MON-DD') BETWEEN (current_date - 7) AND (current_date - 1))
      GROUP BY d.deploy_location
     ) d
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```